# How to avoid login again and again while testing in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I want to automate a web application. It requires Login every time I run the test. I want to bypass this login step and to access the desired URL directly. Below is my code and it is not working as per my need.

```
class practice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
WebDriver driver;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();


options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 1");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:///chromedriver.exe");
driver=new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https:xyz.com/dashboard/campaigns#display=active&page=1&view=list&sort=startdate&sort_order=desc&region=all&search=");

// If login page appears
if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sessions_new']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h2")).isDisplayed())
{
System.out.println("This is login page");



driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sessions_new\"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(
    "wadfd@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sessions_new\"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/input")).sendKeys(
    "abc123");
driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();

}

// if required page appears
else
{
System.out.println("This is NOT login page");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/section[1]/nav/ul/li[2]/a/span")).click();
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could go wrong when I see your code below, so it's hard to tell you what to fix (Is it crashing? Which line?), but I don't see any interaction like `.click()` after you do the `sendKeys` actions.
So to me, it looks like in the `if` block, when you are on login page, you fill your credentials but never press a login button.

Just another point: you should avoid using `Thread.sleep` like plage. Try to look for `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(<put here a selector for a element you want to see loaded>));` or any similar ExpectedConditions for a cleaner and more efficient use of Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are two solutions you could try, when you want to reduce login times and save running time.

1. If you use TestNG, just put Login in the BeforeClass(), so that all test() in this class only need Login once.
2. If the web application keep login authentication information in cookie, you can login manually and extract the cookie, then after some format conversion you can pass cookie to driver. A demo like this:

```java
// Tip: firstly convert the raw cookie String to List<Cookie>, 
// then call the below in for-loop

driver.manage().addCookie(Cookie cookie);
```

However, I think, option 2 is not a good solution in the actual project testing, just an idea for your reference.